# Is this working? Am I mining?

Tags: mining

Sorry I'm new to this whole ether mining.I don't use geth as a video I saw said : you don't need to use that in a pool mining. Just installed etherminer and created a wallet with myetherwallet.cx put it into the cli and hit run. This is the output below. Is this working as it should? Thanks

```
Creating cache buffer
Creating DAG buffer
Loading kernels
Writing cache buffer
Creating buffer for header.
Creating mining buffer 0
Creating mining buffer 1
  i  06:54:08|GPU0  2.01GB of DAG data generated in 2079301 ms.
  m  06:54:08|main  Mining on PoWhash #90994b0b : 21=21MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  06:54:09|main  Got work package: #04700f3b
  m  06:55:24|main  Mining on PoWhash #04700f3b : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  06:55:25|main  Got work package: #45aaaba8
  m  06:56:39|main  Mining on PoWhash #45aaaba8 : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  06:56:40|main  Got work package: #3efec77b
  m  06:57:24|main  Mining on PoWhash #3efec77b : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  06:57:25|main  Got work package: #f40182a2
  m  06:58:10|main  Mining on PoWhash #f40182a2 : 10.5=10.5MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  06:58:10|main  Got work package: #8dcb64c5
  m  06:59:25|main  Mining on PoWhash #8dcb64c5 : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  06:59:25|main  Got work package: #5a12e36c
  m  07:00:40|main  Mining on PoWhash #5a12e36c : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  X  07:00:50|main  Failed to submit hashrate.
  X  07:00:50|main  Dynamic exception type: class jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32003 : Client connector error: libcurl error: 28 -> Operation timed out

  m  07:00:50|main  Got work package: #d132e52e
  m  07:01:25|main  Mining on PoWhash #d132e52e : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:01:26|main  Got work package: #b801f140
  m  07:02:10|main  Mining on PoWhash #b801f140 : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:02:11|main  Got work package: #c5a32488
  m  07:03:25|main  Mining on PoWhash #c5a32488 : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:03:26|main  Got work package: #a0ffa151
  m  07:04:41|main  Mining on PoWhash #a0ffa151 : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:04:41|main  Got work package: #00bec7cb
  m  07:05:26|main  Mining on PoWhash #00bec7cb : 14.7=14.7MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:05:26|main  Got work package: #42d249c9
  m  07:06:11|main  Mining on PoWhash #42d249c9 : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:06:12|main  Got work package: #2727a0a9
  m  07:07:26|main  Mining on PoWhash #2727a0a9 : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:07:27|main  Got work package: #ea7b0db9
  m  07:08:41|main  Mining on PoWhash #ea7b0db9 : 10.5=10.5MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:08:42|main  Got work package: #8b33da6f
  m  07:09:26|main  Mining on PoWhash #8b33da6f : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:09:27|main  Got work package: #6fdd1e06
  m  07:10:12|main  Mining on PoWhash #6fdd1e06 : 14.7=14.7MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:10:12|main  Got work package: #b08972ad
  m  07:11:27|main  Mining on PoWhash #b08972ad : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:11:28|main  Got work package: #afa1a9a1
  m  07:12:42|main  Mining on PoWhash #afa1a9a1 : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:12:46|main  Got work package: #e25c6ffc
  m  07:13:27|main  Mining on PoWhash #e25c6ffc : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:13:28|main  Got work package: #bac5b7f6
  m  07:14:12|main  Mining on PoWhash #bac5b7f6 : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:13|main  Got work package: #3f1d4814
  m  07:14:16|main  Mining on PoWhash #3f1d4814 : 4.19=4.19MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:17|main  Got work package: #48c377a1
  m  07:14:24|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 14.7=14.7MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:25|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:26|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:27|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:28|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:29|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:30|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:31|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:31|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:32|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:33|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:34|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:35|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:36|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:37|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:38|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:39|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:40|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:41|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:42|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:43|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:44|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:44|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:45|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:46|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:47|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:48|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:49|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:50|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:51|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:52|main  Mining on PoWhash #48c377a1 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:14:52|main  Got work package: #08ef1a57
  m  07:15:50|main  Mining on PoWhash #08ef1a57 : 2.1=2.1MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:15:50|main  Got work package: #f6af62c5
  m  07:16:34|main  Mining on PoWhash #f6af62c5 : 4.19=4.19MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:16:35|main  Got work package: #907c690f
  m  07:16:45|main  Mining on PoWhash #907c690f : 4.19=4.19MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:16:46|main  Got work package: #4c7fb923
  m  07:17:18|main  Mining on PoWhash #4c7fb923 : 12.6=12.6MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:17:19|main  Got work package: #82863819
  m  07:18:40|main  Mining on PoWhash #82863819 : 6.29=6.29MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:18:41|main  Got work package: #0289c739
  m  07:19:25|main  Mining on PoWhash #0289c739 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  X  07:19:35|main  Failed to submit hashrate.
  X  07:19:35|main  Dynamic exception type: class jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32003 : Client connector error: libcurl error: 28 -> Operation timed out

  m  07:19:36|main  Got work package: #2cbffc7f
  m  07:20:40|main  Mining on PoWhash #2cbffc7f : 10.5=10.5MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:20:41|main  Got work package: #246c2d78
  m  07:20:54|main  Mining on PoWhash #246c2d78 : 16.8=16.8MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:20:55|main  Got work package: #b00e0138
  m  07:23:16|main  Mining on PoWhash #b00e0138 : 0=0MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:23:17|main  Got work package: #205ac20c
  m  07:23:42|main  Mining on PoWhash #205ac20c : 2.1=2.1MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:23:43|main  Got work package: #98f20029
  m  07:25:35|main  Mining on PoWhash #98f20029 : 4.19=4.19MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:25:36|main  Got work package: #23d76ae6
  m  07:26:22|main  Mining on PoWhash #23d76ae6 : 4.19=4.19MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:26:23|main  Got work package: #a571f687
  m  07:27:27|main  Mining on PoWhash #a571f687 : 2.1=2.1MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:27:36|main  Got work package: #834933bd
  m  07:28:42|main  Mining on PoWhash #834933bd : 14.7=14.7MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:28:43|main  Got work package: #75476f93
  m  07:29:27|main  Mining on PoWhash #75476f93 : 10.5=10.5MH/s A0+0:R0+0
  m  07:29:28|main  Got work package: #b415ac36
```

Comment: Dude you are mining.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are mining. However, I would recommend double checking that your wallet ID is correctly typed into the mining local config file. Having the wrong wallet ID would be unfortunate to find out about days later and realize your coins have been sent to someone else.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did input the wallet number from the website into the bat configuration file. So what's the deal here, do I just leave my PC doing this and any findings just go into the wallet? How soon does ethereum pay out, looking at my current hash rate?

Comment: @rajB Are you mining in a pool?